# Want create rows and columns based on item selection and item size selection want to create same as below HTML table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>table</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
    .err{border:1px solid red; outline:none;}
    .txtfld:readonly{border:none;}
    .txtfld{ width:50px;}
    </style>
    <body>
                    <div><span>Items:<br>
                    <select class="items">
                    <option value="">Select Items</option>
                    <option value="">Items 6356</option>
                    <option value="">Items 5700</option>
                    <option value="">Items 500</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" value="Add Items"/>
                    <hr>
                    <div>Item sizes:<br>
                    <p><input type="checkbox"> 8x10 in</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox"> 8x10 in Mammo</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox"> 10x12 in</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox"> 10x12 in Memmo</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox"> 11x14 in</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox"> 14x14 in</p>
                <p><input type="checkbox"> 14x17 in</p>
                    </div>
                    </span>
                    <table width="580" border="1" class="printer-row">
                                       <tbody><tr>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>8X10 in</td>
                                         <td>10X12 in</td>
                                         <td>8X10 in Memmo</td>
                                         <td>10X12 in Memmo</td>
                                         <td>11X14 in</td>
                                         <td>14X14 in</td>
                                         <td>14X17 in</td>
                                         <td>Total sheets/year</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                         <td>Item 5700</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit" readonly=""></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                         <td>Item 5700</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                         <td>Item 400</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                         <td>Item 3000</td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       <tr>
                                         <td>Total sheets/year</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       </tr>
                                     </tbody></table>

    </body

> Blockquote

    </html>
```

I want to create the table rows and columns based on the Item select options "Add more" button will append the "new item" based on that selected items i want to create rows with selected item names. In second case based on "Item size" checkbox i need to create column with their respective names" you may refer the HTML Table to more clarification

Comment: You've forgotten to paste the code you've already tried, please paste that too.

Comment: i have posted only html. I need the js functanality for the requirement pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, I have added the feature

Point to check:
- I have added a javascript fucntion add_row() and calling on click of add button.

- I have added value to select dropdown.

  table

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function  add_row() {
        var row_name = $('select').val();

        if (row_name != "") {
              var row = $('<tr><td>' + row_name + '</td></tr>');

              $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {

                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                   row.append('<td><input class="txtfld" type="text" placeholder="edit"></td>')
                } else {
                     row.append('<td></td>')
                }

            })
            row.append('<td></td>')
          $("table.printer-row tbody tr:last").before(row)
        }
      }

  </script>
  </head>
  <style>
  .err{border:1px solid red; outline:none;}
  .txtfld:readonly{border:none;}
  .txtfld{ width:50px;}
  </style>


  <body>
                  <div><span>Items:<br>
                  <select class="items">
                  <option value="">Select Items</option>
                  <option value="Items 6356">Items 6356</option>
                  <option value="Items 5700">Items 5700</option>
                  <option value="Items 500">Items 500</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                  <input type="button" value="Add Items" onclick="add_row();">
                  <hr>
                  <div>Item sizes:<br>
                  <p><input type="checkbox"> 8x10 in</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox"> 8x10 in Mammo</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox"> 10x12 in</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox"> 10x12 in Memmo</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox"> 11x14 in</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox"> 14x14 in</p>
              <p><input type="checkbox"> 14x17 in</p>
                  </div>
                  </span>
                  <table width="580" border="1" class="printer-row">
                                     <tbody><tr>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>8X10 in</td>
                                       <td>10X12 in</td>
                                       <td>8X10 in Memmo</td>
                                       <td>10X12 in Memmo</td>
                                       <td>11X14 in</td>
                                       <td>14X14 in</td>
                                       <td>14X17 in</td>
                                       <td>Total sheets/year</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <td>Item 5700</td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit" readonly=""></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <td>Item 5700</td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <td>Item 400</td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <td>Item 3000</td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="txtfld" placeholder="edit"></td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                     </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                       <td>Total sheets/year</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                     </tr>
                                   </tbody></table>

  </body> Blockquote

  </html>
  ```

Comment: thanks but not much helpful i done that but by second is how do i calculate that rows and columns total.Please check my next link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322113/how-to-calculating-column-and-row-sum-in-html-table-using-jquery